# How to call fragment inside a fragment and display to same layout

Tags: java, android-studio

I am using bottom navigation and call fragment(Ex. Home) inside its define Framelayout(ID: flayout) when click the button Home. What I want to know if is it possible to call another fragment(Ex. Buy) inside fragment(Home) and display it to Framelayout(ID: flayout)? How to find Framelayout ID in fragment(Buy) since it has different layout? Thank You!

I can call my other fragments with no problem in bottomnavigation. This is the code for my **bottomnavigation.java**

```
bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id){
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fragment = new Home();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_buy:
                    fragment = new Buy();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_sell:
                    fragment = new Sell();
                    break;
            }
            final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    });
    fragment = new Home();
    final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

When I go to Home(), and call another fragment like Buy() in Home(). How to access and display the Buy() to the (R.id.content) Framelayout since it is located in **bottomnavigation.java** xml layout. Is it possible?

Comment: What did you already try? Give us some information like code snippets, environment and stuff so we can understand the problem.

Comment: I updated my question sir. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for change fragment:

```
     getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

     final   FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

     transaction.addToBackStack(null);
     transaction.replace(R.id.flayout, new Buy());

     transaction.commit();
```